# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am failed to find the solution for this error...

here is my error...

```
org.json.JSONException:Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

here is my JSON :

```
[{"name":"Muhaimin","address":"Sylhet","bgroup":"o+"}]
```

The java Class code

```
entpackage com.example.blood;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView resultView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    resultView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    getData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getData()
{
    String result="";
    InputStream isr=null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/blood/index.php");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         httppost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");
        HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        isr=entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        String err=e.toString();
        resultView.setText("Could not connect to database"+err);
        Log.e("error", err);
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        String err2=e.toString();
        resultView.setText("Error coverting result"+err2);
        Log.e("error", err2);
    }
    try{
        String s="";
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s= s + 
                    "Name :"+json.getString("name")+"\n"+
                    "Blood Group :"+json.getString("bgroup")+"\n" +
                    "Address :"+json.getString("address")+"\n\n";
        }
        resultView.setText(s);
    }catch(Exception e){
        String err1=e.toString();
        resultView.setText("xxx"+err1);
        Log.e("error", err1);
    }
}

}
```

When i run the application it show String can not coverted to JSONArray. Also I am working on localhost. Now how can i solve this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: somehow i get the feeling your index.php isnt returning your json how you think it is. You might try printing out its value before you parse it?

Comment: php code:
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","BloodDB");
 mysql_select_db("BloodDB",$con);
 
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT name,address,bgroup FROM tbl_blood_donor");
 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $output[]=$row;
 }
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: i am printing value before parsing

Comment: your response string starts with `<!DOCTYPE`, why? I have no idea, you might try logging the output before you initialize the JSONArray to see the exact response. Likely an error page.

Comment: I receive almost the same from server using http connection. What I do is not read html tags (starting with **<**).